# I18n : Heavy Js application, where should translation goes?

Tags: internationalization, translation, frontend, backend

I've recently got confuse about a talk I had with the front end developer working with me. 
We were talking about where should translation goes in a context of an heavy Javascript client side application.

From my point of view, some translations such as for example validation errors messages or some others server side string can be handle by the backend. However, the rest of the text has to be handled by the front end framework.

But the other guy maintain his position by saying that the backend should handled all of them and provide the front end with translation strings using JSON.

For me this sounds kind of dumb but well, no ones can be 100% right so I would like to know your point of view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the translation should be passed from backend let say hidden fields or json and developer should be able to pick the translations and use them in javascript. Regardless of the language used on the page javascript will work smoothly and consistently.